# How bind Margin or thickness from userControl in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, multibinding

i search many time and times,and bald my head
so can't find full simple example.

i create a user control in WPF that has four textbox(right,left,top,down captions).
when i use that User Control in my Window,i simply wanna bind Those value to my Thickness or margin of Some Element Such as Stroke thickness of rectangle.

please give me simple and complete example.
thanks a lot!

Comment: Not very sure what you are asking. Rephrase your question and/or add some sample codes of what you did.

Comment: Declare a Thickness dependency property in your UserControl. Attach four event handlers to the TextChanged event of the four TextBoxes that update the value of the Thickness property. Do not use string.Empty as the default value of the Thickness property.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a few steps:
1. Create 4 dependency properties inside the user control (for the purpose of the example I named them Text1 to Text4):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text2Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text2", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Text3
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text3Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text3Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text3Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text3", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Text4
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text4Property); }
        set { SetValue(Text4Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text4Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Text4", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

2. Next, in the XAML of the UserControl add 4 TextBox controls and bind them in the following manner:

```xaml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text3, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text4, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

3. Place the UserControl in whichever window you want to use it and bind the Text1 to Text4 properties to other controls and properties in the window (for the example, I connected the properties to the Title property of the window):

```xaml
<local:MyUserControl Text1="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
    Text2="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
    Text3="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
    Text4="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

**Update:** A simple thickness to string converter that can be used to bind to a property such as Margin:

```
public class ThicknessToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Thickness thikness = (Thickness)value;

        return $"{thikness.Left},{thikness.Top},{thikness.Right},{thikness.Bottom}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Because you are not using a view/view model, validation should go here!
        string[] thicknessValues = ((string)value).Split(',');

        return new Thickness(double.Parse(thicknessValues[0]),
            double.Parse(thicknessValues[1]),
            double.Parse(thicknessValues[2]),
            double.Parse(thicknessValues[3]));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank for your help dear friend.
i understand your code completely.
but my main problem is how to bind these four value to margin with converter or change dependencyProperty type to Thickness like this:

DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(Thickness ), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty))
thank again